# My datepicker is not working that well

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory-leaks, datepicker

**Hi my friendly computer wizards!**

I coded a simple datepicker in jQuery, the already finished packages was to heavy for my taste. I thought everything was a-ok until I noticed strange behaviour. I first decided it might have been the alcohol messing up the latency between my eyes and my brain, but when, after waking up, the problem persisted I decided to find help.

> When I repeatedly click one of the arrows to change month, the script
>   starts to lagg behind and eventually stalls. After a while it comes
>   back to life. Approximately the first four or five month-changes work
>   as intended.

I have been trying to simplify the Date() calls to the best of my limited knowledge, but to no avail. Do I have some kind of memory leak?

I fiddled up an example that replicates the problem here (**complete code**): http://jsfiddle.net/DCfMj/

Any help is appreciated. It is also okay to say that I have written immensly crappy code and that I am a worthless sack of blood because of it. Constructive criticism like that builds character.

Comment: Why don't you use `:hover` in CSS?

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers.  Use a different attribute instead.

Comment: Because it's an huge library and I want full control of every aspect. It's for a site with crazy load and every kb saved is worth a lot. Not using :hover is just plain lack of knowledge.

Comment: That isn't a good reason not to use jQuery UI.  You can load it from Google's CDN for zero bandwidth.

Comment: Apparantly I am ignorant of more than one thing. I might go in that direction, but I am still interested in what I've done wrong.

Comment: One other reason: I want to learn how to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `$(...).datepicker`, you're adding another `click` handler.

Eventually, it starts taking a long time to run all of those handlers.

Comment: That makes sense, can I somehow unbind the handler after each event, or is it more sensible to invoke it in some other way?

Comment: You can call `die()`, or you can just add the handlers once.

Comment: Thank you, I just moved the functions outside the datepicker() function.